# Omnifaces extensionless URLs and h:link

Tags: jsf-2.2, omnifaces

According to http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs by default, all URLs generated by ViewHandler.getActionURL(FacesContext, String), which is used by among others

```
<h:form>, <h:link>, <h:button>
```

and all extended tags, will also be extensionless.

I try using this by putting Facelets source files into /WEB-INF/faces-views directory.

I typed /context/entries in the browser and I got the page in /WEB-INF/faces-views/entries.xhtml.  But when I used this in my facelet page:

```
<h:link outcome="entries">Entries</h:link>
```

The url resulted is /context/WEB-INF/faces-views/entries.xhtml which is not the desirable result.  What went wrong?

I am using Mojara 2.2.12 and Omnifaces 2.6.9 and my faces servlet mapping is *.jsf.

Comment: Why do you use `*.jsf` suffix as servlet mapping? That's related with old JSF 1.x style. Switch to `*.xhtml` instead.

Comment: Change to 2.6.8 solves the problem.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a [small mistake](http://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/455) in FacesViews of specifically 2.6.9 which is fixed in 2.7-SNAPSHOT. While working on getting FacesViews to [support](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/449) folders with periods in names such as `/foo.bar/baz`, I have accidentally committed a part of the fix into 3.x only instead of into 2.x. That explains why it works just fine in 3.1, as demonstrated by the ["viewsdemo"](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/viewsdemo) showcase. My mistake, this just proves again that I'm a human and not a machine.

There are a few options to get around this:

1. Downgrade to 2.6.8.
2. Or, migrate to 3.1.
3. Or, keep 2.6.9 and use the ["Minimal configuration"](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs) approach of a single `web.xml` context parameter instead of "Zero configuration" approach of placing files in `/WEB-INF/faces-views`.

Answer (score 0):

BalusC is right, switching to version 2.6.8 solves the problem.  The credit is BalusC's as always, but he has too much credit so I think he wouldn't mind that I posted an answer myself, just don't want to bother him.

Change the servlet mapping to *.xhtml also solves the problem.  With all due respect, Xtreme Biker: a bug is a bug.  Even if I change the mapping to *.abc there should not be a problem.

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer. I have initially posted my "answer" as a comment, because I wasn't sure if it was the correct answer.